# How can I patch a class in a dependency library using Gradle (or some other tool)

Tags: android, gradle, apk, mapbox, patch

I have an Android app that depends on `@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl` and somewhere down the dependency chain the class `com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.utils.TelemetryUtils` is imported, but it has a bug that I need to fix without upgrading the library (this would force me to update a ton of stuff on this app, and I just need it working again).

I already have the source code (`TelemetryUtils.java`) and have already fixed the bug there, so my idea is to somehow override or patch the class, i.e. somehow get the bug fixed in the final APK. Unfortunately my Gradle skills are almost non-existent and I failed to find a solution that actually works.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: To my knowledge gradle build will fail if you try to include a class twice, so the only chance I see is building a modified version of the library (if the library is open-source) or trying modifying the class file in the cached library JAR on your system.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the tips, I could build a modified version of the library, but I don't depend on it directly, it's another dependency of mine that does, how can I then swap the library so that the dependency picks it instead of the original one? One option could be to replace all the libraries in the dependency chain, at least then I have full control, but it's going to be a pain to find the full source code for all of them...

Comment: As you can only use one version of a library in a project, adding the library as direct dependency usually overrides the version that is added as nested dependency.